# Vertically center div contained in floating div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's inside a float:left div and it doesn't want to vertically align.  I thought I could completely fill the floated div with the inner div and set that one to display: table-cell, but it doesn't seem to want to both FILL the div and allow this display?

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/K22Vm/)

```
<div id="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="">
    <div id="DivToCenter">
        <div id="ButtonContainer">
            <ul>
            <li><div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Report an Issue</a></div></li>
            <li><div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Report an Issue</a></div></li>                        
            <li><div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Report an Issue</a></div></li>
            <li><div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Report an Issue</a></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
#tabs-3 { /* Tab Content Panel (Right Panel)*/
    float: left;
    min-height: 300px; /* How tall is our tab box, minimum?*/
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}

#DivToCenter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#ButtonContainer {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#ButtonContainer > ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block; 
}

#ButtonContainer > ul > li {
 display: inline-block; /*Puts the buttons in a line*/   
}

.TemplateButton {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.ui-tabs-panel.ui-widget-content .TemplateButton > a {
    /* SHAPE */
    width: 119px;
    height: 119px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    /* ALIGNMENT */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    /* STYLING */
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0c428f;
}

.ui-tabs-panel.ui-widget-content .TemplateButton > a:hover {
    background-color: #6795bb;
}
```

Comment: acutally I dont get your question? `display:table:cell` seems to work perfectly. Try resizing the output window and you can see what I am saying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display: table;` to `#tabs-3`

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K22Vm/5/)

Comment: hmm, I don't see the change I was expecting?  My hope was that the "green" would be vertically centered with equal pink above and below...